# Meta name description in og:description

Tags: seo, google, html

I would like to ask if is there any difference when I have **description** and **og:description** separately and together. Is there just only difference that when it's separately I can add different text and when it's together, so same text is used for both ?

```
<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum" />

<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum" />
```

Together

```
<meta property="og:description" name="description" content="Lorem ipsum">
```

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in implementing Open Graph(OG) along with the description and same is the case for twitter cards.

Different platforms prefer different descriptions and they would be free to go ahead with the one they see fit. (facebook prefers open graph, twitter prefers Twitter cards).

And yes, the format that you used for implementing them together i.e

```
<meta property="og:description" name="description" content="Lorem ipsum">
```

will work properly.

You can run your Html code with this tag on Facebook's [URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

Different search engines, and social media networks, will show one or the other. For example, Facebook will tend to use the Open Graph tag. It doesn't hurt to have them both. Unless you're concerned about fine-tuning the description on a certain website, I wouldn't worry about setting up a separate meta description and Open Graph description.

Comment: Is they syntax they propose for putting them both in the same tag OK?

Comment: Twitter prefers twitter cards.

Comment: Corrected above.